# How to fix redeclaration error: class member cannot be redeclared in C++

Tags: c++, overloading, redeclaration

Attempting to overload a member function of a class, a redeclaration error occurred.

In class declarations even Qt reveal a problem:

```
error: class member cannot be redeclared
note: previous declaration is here
```

This message is provided for the classes marked as "overload2" in the code below:

```
template <class GraphReaderType, class GraphType>
class GraphsDataset {

public:

    template <typename BoostGraphsContainer, typename LabelsContainer>
    bool readDataset(const std::string& datasetPath, BoostGraphsContainer& graphsContainer, LabelsContainer& labels) const;

    // "Overload 1"
    template <typename BoostGraphsContainer, typename LabelsContainer, typename IdsContainer>
    bool readDataset(const std::string& datasetPath, BoostGraphsContainer& graphsContainer, LabelsContainer& labels,
             IdsContainer& ids) const;
    //"Overload 2"
    template <typename BoostGraphsContainer, typename LabelsContainer, typename uniqueLabelContainer>
    bool readDataset(const std::string& datasetPath, BoostGraphsContainer& graphsContainer, LabelsContainer& labels, uniqueLabelContainer& labelsSet) const;
...
}
```

The compilation fails complaining about overloading.

```
GraphsDataset.hpp:120: error: ‘template<class GraphReaderType, class GraphType> template<class BoostGraphsContainer, class LabelsContainer, class uniqueLabelContainer> bool spare::GraphsDataset<GraphReaderType, GraphType>::readDataset(const string&, BoostGraphsContainer&, LabelsContainer&, uniqueLabelContainer&) const’ cannot be overloaded
     bool readDataset(const std::string& datasetPath, BoostGraphsContainer& graphsContainer, LabelsContainer& labels, uniqueLabelContainer& labelsSet) const;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

The compilation works if one among "Overload 1/2" member function is deleted.

Why these functions can't be overloaded together?

Comment: you have exactly the same definitions but you just renamed the template parameter, endeing in twice the exact same thing. You need to tell us more about what is different between the 2 overloaded versions

Comment: `IdsContainer` and `uniqueLabelContainer` seem to be same type - at least for this particular template instantiation.

Comment: you have the same problem when you declare a `template <typename T> foo(T t);` and a `template <typename S> foo(S t);`

Comment: In a template point of view, it's exaclty like declare two functions `double f(double x);` and `double f(double y);`. To solve your problem, we have to knwo what you expect to do.

Comment: The names of a template's parameters are irrelevant  - you have two declarations of `template<typename A, typename B, typename C> bool readDataSet(const std::string&, A&, B&, C&) const;`

Comment: I understand but these two template parameters are not the same. `IdsContainer` is a `std::vector<string>` , `uniqueLabelContainer` is a `std::set<string>`. Anyway, how can the compile know the type in compiling time?

Comment: @LucaJungla No, they're not - the types are parameters (with those names) for the templates. If you want to overload on specific types, do that.

Comment: @molbdnilo Replacing the type parameter from `uniqueLabelContainer` to `std::set<string>`, the problem disappear. I still confused in how the compiler check this issue.

Comment: I think you would be helped by reading some more about templates (and types) in [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Ok, then what you need is probably "template specialization".